# Exception while running EvoSuite tests related to Security manager

Tags: java, evosuite, java-security-manager

I'm trying to run EvoSuite tests with this [tutorial](http://www.evosuite.org/documentation/tutorial-part-1/).

I'm able to generate test classes and compile them using java 8.
However, when try to run it using the below command, an exception is thrown.

```
java  -cp ".\log4j.jar;.\ojdbc6.jar;.\commons-codec-1.3.jar;.\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar;.\slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar;D:\proj\target\classes;.\evosuite-tests;.\evosuite-standalone-runtime-1.0.6.jar;.\junit-4.12.jar;.\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;"   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  com.u.g.KeyClient_ESTest
```

Thrown Exception:

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Security manager blocks ("java.sql.SQLPermission" "deregisterDriver")
    java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1556)
    org.evosuite.runtime.sandbox.MSecurityManager.checkPermission(MSecurityManager.java:434)
    java.sql.DriverManager.deregisterDriver(DriverManager.java:402)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:467)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    com.u.g.KeyClient.getFromJDBC(KeyClient.java:164)
    com.u.g.KeyClient.fetchKey(KeyClient.java:95)
    com.u.g.KeyClient.<init>(KeyClient.java:40)
    com.u.g.KeyClient.getInstance(KeyClient.java:48)
    com.u.g.KeyClient_ESTest.test1(KeyClient_ESTest.java:36)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:298)
    org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:292)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at org.evosuite.runtime.sandbox.MSecurityManager.checkPermission(MSecurityManager.java:452)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.deregisterDriver(DriverManager.java:402)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:467)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.u.g.KeyClient.getFromJDBC(KeyClient.java:164)
    at com.u.g.KeyClient.fetchKey(KeyClient.java:95)
    at com.u.g.KeyClient.<init>(KeyClient.java:40)
    at com.u.g.KeyClient.getInstance(KeyClient.java:48)
    at com.u.g.KeyClient_ESTest.test1(KeyClient_ESTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    FAILURES!!!
    Tests run: 2,  Failures: 1
```

Can someone please help/guide me to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Additional Info:

The test class is a singleton, which connects to the database using JDBC API to retrieve certain values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution which worked for me.
The solution was to generate test claasses with below cmd option

> -Dsandbox_mode=OFF

Complete command to generate test classes is

```
C:\java8\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java  -jar evosuite-master-1.0.6.jar -Dsandbox_mode=OFF -class com.u.g.KeyClient -projectCP ".\log4j.jar;.\ojdbc6.jar;.\commons-codec-1.3.jar;.\target\classes;"
```

The corresponding KeyClient_ESTest_scaffolding class will have RuntimeSetting to turn off sandbox

```
@BeforeClass 
public static void initEvoSuiteFramework() { 
org.evosuite.runtime.RuntimeSettings.className = "com.ultimatix.gdpr.KeyClient"; 
org.evosuite.runtime.GuiSupport.initialize(); 
org.evosuite.runtime.RuntimeSettings.maxNumberOfThreads = 100; 
org.evosuite.runtime.RuntimeSettings.maxNumberOfIterationsPerLoop = 10000; 
org.evosuite.runtime.RuntimeSettings.mockSystemIn = true; 
org.evosuite.runtime.RuntimeSettings.sandboxMode = org.evosuite.runtime.sandbox.Sandbox.SandboxMode.OFF; 
org.evosuite.runtime.sandbox.Sandbox.initializeSecurityManagerForSUT(); 
org.evosuite.runtime.classhandling.JDKClassResetter.init();
setSystemProperties();
initializeClasses();
org.evosuite.runtime.Runtime.getInstance().resetRuntime();
```

}

Hope it helps someone facing similar problem.